# How can I enforce a query timeout for MS SQL Server queries run via the MS JDBC Driver?

Tags: sql-server, jdbc

How can we get the MS JDBC Driver to throw a timeout error after n seconds?

**Background**

We have an application that by default uses the Microsoft JDBC driver (version 4.0) to query SQL Server 2014.

Most of the time, queries take 10-20 seconds to finish.  However, from time-to-time the queries take more than 5 minutes to complete.

We'd like the queries that take more than 5 minutes to be seen as an error by the application.  Currently the application provides no timeout settings, so we are left researching timeout settings for the MS JDBC Driver, but I can't find anything to mark long running queries with a timeout error.

I *have* found timeout settings for the jTDS driver (socketTimeout).

Is there an equivalent "socketTimeout" or "queryTimeout" for the MS Driver?  I've tried all of the following and none of them work for the MS Driver:

```
#None of these enforce a timeout with the MS Driver
jdbc:sqlserver://hostname\instanceName;databaseName=mydb;queryTimeout=10
jdbc:sqlserver://hostname\instanceName;databaseName=mydb;socketTimeout=10
jdbc:sqlserver://hostname\instanceName;databaseName=mydb;queryTimeout=10


#This works great with the jTDS driver:
jdbc:sqlserver://hostname\instanceName;databaseName=mydb;socketTimeout=10
```

Comment: All valid connection properties are documented here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378988.aspx there is nothing similar to the query timeout. You will need to set that manually on each `Statement`: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#setQueryTimeout-int-

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - those methods are down at the java code level... and I don't have access to the java code (since this is a purchased application).  I guess I can submit an enhancement request to the vendor to give us a setting in the GUI the will pass a timeout value to the `Statement` `setQueryTimeout(int seconds)` method.  (Or I suppose I can switch drivers?)

Comment: Is there a way to set a timeout with connection hooks?

Comment: Nevermind, I don't see any timeout settings that are available via `SET` statements: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190356.aspx

Answer (score 4):

Microsoft MSSQL-JDBC is now Open sourced. Recently MSSQL-JDBC team implemented [sockettimeout](https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-jdbc/wiki/SocketTimout) & [querytimeout](https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-jdbc/wiki/QueryTimeout)s. This will definitely solve your problem.

With Connection Query:

```
String conURL = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;userName=sa;password=PASSW0RD;database=master;queryTimeout=5";
SQLServerConnection con = (SQLServerStatement) DriverManager.getConnection(conURL);
```

or with DataSource....

```
SQLServerDataSource ds = new SQLServerDataSource();
ds.setUser("sa");  
ds.setPassword("PASSWORD");  
ds.setServerName("localhost");  
ds.setPortNumber(1433);   
ds.setDatabaseName("master");
ds.setQueryTimeout(5);
SQLServerConnection con = (SQLServerConnection) ds.getConnection();
```

Ref: https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-jdbc/wiki/QueryTimeout

Comment: Will this actually kill the query running in the db, or just free up the connection in the app and leave the query running?

Comment: also worths to check cancelQueryTimeout ^v6.4, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/setting-the-connection-properties?view=sql-server-ver16