# SQL Server JDBC driver can't detect lost connection quickly

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, connection-timeout, mssql-jdbc

I'm using JDBC Driver `sqlserver-jdbc-4.0.jar` to connect to SQL Server. I created a connection and used it successfully.

Then I turned off the network interface of the SQL Server machine. When I run the next command, the JDBC driver on the side of my application requires about 15 minutes to understand that the connection is lost. I tried several things:

1. configured JDBC driver properties `LoginTimeout=5, LockTimeout=5, QueryTimeout=5` (5 seconds)
2. called `Statement.setQueryTimeout()` to set timeout to 5 seconds
3. called `Connection.isValid()` with 5 seconds timeout - it also stuck for 15 minutes

Another possible option - `Connection.setNetworkTimeout()` but it is not implemented by the SQL Server driver. I also can not reach the socket used by the JDBC driver to set up TCP Keepalive on it.

If I close the connection and then open it again, it immediately understands that SQL Server instance is unreachable.

How can I overcome my problem and detect lost connection within several seconds instead of 15 minutes?

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36553857/how-can-i-enforce-a-query-timeout-for-ms-sql-server-queries-run-via-the-ms-jdbc?rq=1 I'm afraid the conclusion is: there is no option for this.

Comment: However, the SQL Server JDBC driver is now open source, so you could add it yourself ;) https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-jdbc

Comment: That, or try out the [JTDS](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/) driver, see if you can get the behaviour you want with that one. In other areas I've found it to be the better driver.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft MSSQL-JDBC is now Open sourced. Recently MSSQL-JDBC team implemented [sockettimeout](https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-jdbc/wiki/SocketTimout) & [querytimeout](https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-jdbc/wiki/QueryTimeout)s. This will definitely solve your issue.